# Crashlytics NDK multi androidNdkOut path support

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I use Fabric Crashlytic to impove my native code performance. I have multi .so library in both app project and jar library project. In my app's build.gradle,here it is:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut '<myJarProjectPath>/src/main/obj' //or src/main/obj
    androidNdkLibsOut '<myJarProjectPath>/src/main/jniLibs' //or src/main/jniLibs
}
```

then I use "crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXXRelease" to package my app,and get ndk crash stacktrace in Fabric. But I can only config one of these .so library. I wonder if use "crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXXRelease" to get an Apk, what will happen to .so in jar library project? Does anyone know how to support ndk crashlytics both in  app project and jar library project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matt from Crashlytics here!

**UPDATE**

As of [version 1.23.0](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#july-6-2017), the Fabric plugin supports automatic detection of paths for native binaries when using the Android plugin for Gradle 2.2.0+ with the `externalNativeBuild` DSL. If using this, you should simply remove the `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` properties from your `crashlytics` block.

---

Currently we don't have support for defining multiple directories for your native libraries. However, a very simple workaround for this is to define a Gradle task which copies your debug and release .so files from both projects into a common, temporary directory (e.g. `temp/ndkout/`... and `temp/ndklibsout/`) and then set your `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` properties to those directories.

One thing to note: you'll need to maintain the architecture-specific folder structure under each set of directories! Here's a full example to give you an idea:

```
temp/
-- ndkout/
  -- armeabi
    -- libappproject.so
    -- libjarproject.so
  -- x86
    -- libappproject.so
    -- libjarproject.so
  ...
-- ndklibsout/
  -- armeabi
    -- libappproject.so
    -- libjarproject.so
  -- x86
    -- libappproject.so
    -- libjarproject.so
  ...
```

Comment: you mean this temporary directory is just used for uploading symbol? And so library in both app project and jar library project remain the same?

Comment: I accept this as the answer...But  do hope Fabric can improve it.

Comment: @orcsYang Yes, this temporary directory would just be for uploading symbols, and you can delete it after that task runs. And yes, the .so libraries in both the app project and library project would remain the same, you'd just make copies into the temporary directory. :)