# Crashlytics NDK symbol building from command line

Tags: android-ndk, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

I'm trying to add Crashlytics support to my Android project, which uses NDK and gradle CMake. This means that I need symbols for my shared projects. So if I want to create the symbols for release build I'll call `gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease`

The official document in https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html says that *The symbol generation and upload process assumes a standard project structure: src/main/obj for debug binaries, and src/main/libs for release binaries as produced by ndk-build.*

In the gradle file this means a new block which is like the following:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Because I am using the gradle CMake integration to build my native libs, the default paths of course are not working. My native libraries in release mode are built into a `build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj` directory and in debug mode they go to `build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj` directory.

From trial and error I figured that if I want my release build to work, I'll have to put the path to release mode native libraries into both lines, as illustrated below.

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'
}
```

I just really don't understand the difference between `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` variables, because at least in my scenario they point to same directory. Fortunately this isn't a problem for me because I just need Crashlytics to work with my release binaries.

So my questions are:

1) What is really the difference between `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut`? Why I cannot put a path to my debug binaries in one and path to release binaries to other? A concrete example would be nice in addition to explanation.

2) How should I modify my gradle file if some day I want to include symbols for my debug libraries as well? Meaning that the command
`gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` as well as `gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug` would work?

There is a discussion about this in the threads [Crashlytics NDK symbols and Gradle tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435865/crashlytics-ndk-symbols-and-gradle-tasks) and [Crashlytics NDK multi androidNdkOut path support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735332/crashlytics-ndk-multi-androidndkout-path-support) but they really don't answer to these two questions.

Comment: Did you get the line numbers working? Where did you find the unstripped binary? Those paths you provided are containg only the stripped .so, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work on the Fabric team that maintains our Crashlytics NDK support.

To give some context - our symbol upload tool is based on the `ndk-build` process which produces 2 sets of binaries: your production binaries, which are stripped of symbol data, and debug binaries, which have symbol data intact for debugging purposes.

The Gradle properties map to variables in the `ndk-build` process, specifically:

- `androidNdkOut` is the directory under which the unstripped, debug binaries are placed (equivalent to the `$NDK_OUT` variable in `ndk-build`) called `obj` by default.
- `androidNdkLibsOut` is the directory under which the stripped, release binaries are placed (equivalent to the `$NDK_LIBS_OUT` variable in `ndk-build`) called `libs` by default.

The expected contents of these paths are the architecture-specific directories for your libraries, so for example:

```
obj/
  — armeabi
    — lib1.so
    — lib2.so
  — x86
    — lib1.so
    — lib2.so

libs/
  — armeabi
    — lib1.so
    — lib2.so
  — x86
    — lib1.so
    — lib2.so
```

All you’ll need to do for our symbol upload to work is to generate these same sets of binaries from CMake, and then set your `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` to the appropriate top-level directories where those libraries can be found.

**EDIT/UPDATE July 7, 2017**

We've just released version 1.23.0 of the Fabric plugin for Gradle which supports automatically resolving the appropriate native library paths when you're using the Android Gradle plugin 2.2.0+ with the `externalNativeBuild` DSL, so you no longer have to set `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` if you're using the latest Android Gradle plugin. Check out more info here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#specifying-the-path-to-debug-and-release-binaries

Comment: I have dependency on a native 3rd party module and when I build my project I can't find crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease. can we add ndk support for libraries?

Comment: crashlytics generates the symbols to upload them. But still on the dashboard I can not see the stack trace. gradle tool 3.21, ndk 14,

Comment: Crashlytics no longer seem to be able to do this, filed a bug. Please check my Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931385/error-while-uploading-symbols-to-firebase-crashlytics, would be great if anyome can help

Answer (score 0):

If the automatic detection mentioned by mWillis does not work for you checkout the hidden log file:

```
~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
```

For whatever reason google does not point you to that and it also seems missing from the fabric.io docs.